Optimal implied constant for the classic divisor function bound
One of the most fundamental and useful asymptotic results in number theory is the divisor bound, namely
$$\displaystyle \tau(n) = \# \{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} : xy = n\} = O\left(n^{\frac{1}{\log \log n}} \right).$$
That is, there exists a positive number $C$ such that
$$\displaystyle \tau(n) \leq C n^{\frac{1}{\log \log n}}$$
for all $n \geq 2$, say (this restriction avoids the issue of the right hand side being undefined when $n = 1$).
I have not seen a reference that discusses the nature of $C$. Is it known how large the minimum value of $C$ is?
If we require the condition $n \geq T$, and choose $C(T)$ to be the minimum positive number such that
$$\displaystyle \tau(n) \leq C(T) n^{\frac{1}{\log \log n}}$$
for all $n \geq T$, what can be said about $C(T)$ as a function of $T$?

This is a weird question, since $$d(n) \le n^{\frac{\log 2 + o(1)}{\log \log n}}.$$

More precisely, $\log \tau(n) \leq \log 2\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}+O(\frac{\log n}{(\log\log n)^2})$. So assuming you meant to ask about $\tau(n) \leq C(T) n^{\frac{\log 2}{\log\log n}}$, we have $C(T) \leq n^{O(1/(\log\log n)^2)}$, and taking $n=\prod_{p\leq x}p$ shows this is the correct order of growth of $C(T)$.

These two comments are relevant for the second part of the question, but does not answer the original question which is to compute the smallest $C$ which is valid for all $n \geq 2$ (either with $1/\log \log n$ as in the original question or improved to $\log 2/\log \log n$). I think this requires a non-trivial amount of explicit calculations

This also doesn't quite answer the first question, but worth noting that Nicolas and Robin [Canad. Math. Bull. 26 (1983), no. 4, 485–492] proved that $\frac{\log \tau(n)\log\log n}{\log 2\log n}$ is maximised at $n=6983776800$, where it is $1.5379\cdots$. Therefore $\tau(n) \leq n^{\frac{1.06599\cdots}{\log\log n}}$ for all $n\geq 2$.
